# Postgres 9.3 Search word fragments with full text search

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I am trying to find the appropriate syntax within full text search to search for fragments. I know that something like this:

document @@ to_tsquery('2161:*) will return anything that started with 2161, but if my token is ABC021613 it does not return that  item. What is the syntax to wild card both before and after the 2161?

Comment: probably duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/13072165/5315974

Answer (score 0):

This is because https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/textsearch-controls.html#TEXTSEARCH-PARSING-QUERIES supports prefix matching, but not "suffix"...

I believe it is answered well here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13072165/5315974