# Sanitizing and preparation of text search string for dapper query

Tags: sql, .net, postgresql, .net-6.0, sanitization

We have a table of following structure in `postgresql` (simplified):

```
CREATE TABLE items(
    id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('item_id_seq') PRIMARY KEY,
    name varchar(40) not null,
    name_search tsvector GENERATED ALWAYS AS (to_tsvector('simple', name)) STORED
);
```

Using `C#` as the programming language I would like to make a full text search on `name_search` field. Without full ORM like `EntifyFramework`.

`Dapper` is used and the current query/logic looks like this:

```
    public async Task<IEnumerable<FeedItemInDb>> GetItems(string searchTerm)
    {
        string searchFilter = "";
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchTerm))
        {
            string searchTermProcessed = $"{searchTerm}:*";
            searchTermProcessed = searchTermProcessed.Replace(" ", " & ");

            searchFilter = $"AND i.name_search @@ to_tsquery('simple', '{searchTermProcessed}')";
        }

        var results = await uow.Connection.QueryAsync<FeedItemInDb>($@"select i.* FROM items i WHERE 1=1 {searchFilter}", new
        {
            // params here
        });

        return results;
    }
```

**It works OK for very trivial cases.** For example search string `my test` is sanitized to `my & test:*`

**There is one main flaw with this approach** - you have to know in advance all the sanitization rules required for query! As an example, following raw input `my :*test` ends up with exception:

> Npgsql.PostgresException: 42601: syntax error in tsquery: "my & :*test:*"

I was wondering if there is some kind of package or rules or code in `Dapper` that would do all of the required sanitization work for me? Similarly to how we can parametrize other values in query...

Normally, using `Dapper`, I would expect the code to look like this:

```
    public async Task<IEnumerable<FeedItemInDb>> GetItems(string searchTerm)
    {

        var results = await uow.Connection.QueryAsync<FeedItemInDb>($@"select i.* FROM items i
    WHERE i.name_search @@ to_tsquery('simple', '@SearchParam:*')", new
        {
            SearchParam = searchTerm
        });

        return results;
    }
```

But it does not return any results, unfortunately. Nor with `to_tsquery('simple', '@SearchParam')`.

In general I just want to know how to solve this problem. How to sanitize the string for the full text search using `Dapper`. If the user starts passing `:,.%&*` in a query I would expect my code to start failing if left as is.. Should I maybe prohibit/filter out all special characters from  user input? The problem is I have no idea what I should be filtering out..

**EDIT:**
`to_tsquery('simple', @SearchParam)` does seem to work, if I format the search string manually before the search.. So essentially I have the same problem as before. If the string is not properly formatted then `sql` exception is thrown.. Therefore you have to know and apply in advance all formatting/sanitization rules so the query would not fail. So I still have the same question on how to deal with this situation.

Comment: `plainto_tsquery('simple',...)` will prep the query for you.  It discards punctuation and connects words with ampersands.  It doesn't append `:*` to some random word, but doing that doesn't make much sense anyway so, in the lack of explanation for why you want that, it is probably a good thing that it doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While there is no answer, it found it "somewhat doable" to just replace non-supported characters with a regular expression like so:

```
    private static string CorrectInputString(string input)
    {
        string result = input?.Trim();

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(result))
        {
            // remove newlines and tabs
            result = Regex.Replace(result, @"\t|\n|\r", "");

            // remove not-supported characters (supported are: numbers, regular letters, hyphens, spaces)
            result = Regex.Replace(result, "[^\p{L}0-9- ]", "");

            // remove double spaces (also trims)
            result = string.Join(" ", result.Split(' ', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));
        }

        return result;
    }
```

then

```
    public static string PrepareSearchString(string input)
    {
        string result = input?.Trim();

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(result))
        {
            // prepare query #1
            result = $"{result}:*";

            // prepare query #2
            result = result.Replace(" ", "&");
        }

        return result;
    }
```

I use 2 of these methods in sequence in a helper class.

This of course removes quite a lot of information from the initial input string, exactly what I wanted to avoid doing.. There seems to be another solution for full-text search using `GIST` and `GIN` indexes explained here ([Postgresql prefix wildcard for full text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13071479/postgresql-prefix-wildcard-for-full-text)). It might work better for the given use-case.

I have decided to leave the solution as is (if there is no better answer).

p.s. here is the `unit-test` that covers all kinds of transformations:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public async Task Sanitize_DisplayName()
    {
        var sourceExpected = new List<(string source, string expected)>()
        {
            ("1", "1"),
            ("test", "test"),
            ("test1", "test1"),
            ("test 1", "test 1"),
            ("test-1", "test-1"),
            ("test-test", "test-test"),
            ("test-test test", "test-test test"),
            ("1 test-TEST test", "1 test-TEST test"),
            ("тест", "тест"),
            ("  тест", "тест"),
            (@"
        тест", "тест"), // ENTER here!
            ("test*/!#%^()[]{}", "test"),
            ("te st*/", "te st"),
            ("te  st*/", "te st"),
            ("te   st*/", "te st"),
            ("\t te    st */", "te st"),
            (" te     st */", "te st"),
            ("test ? &", "test"),
            ("test ? &-", "test -"), // !
        };

        foreach (var item in sourceExpected)
        {
            var res = SqlHelper.CorrectInputString(item.source);

            Assert.AreEqual(item.expected, res);
        }
    }
```